# How to share a substring among different strings?

Tags: java, string

I need to read an array of strings, in which each string is composed of two substrings: the first of these substrings is the same for all the strings of the array. The method that reads this array provides an `ArrayList<CharSequence>` argument, so I need a CharSequence in which you can set the reference to the common substring, and of course variable subsequence, in a way like the following:

```
public class MyCharSequence implements CharSequence {

    public MyCharSequence(CharSequence common, CharSequence append) {
        // ...
    }

    // other CharSequence method
    // ...
}
```

The implementation is very simple, but I was wondering whether there was already a class that would allow to do something like this.

Comment: Are you expecting to separate `common` and `append` charsequences from your `ArrayList<CharSequence>` object?

Comment: Is this a 'homework' problem, or a real-world problem?

Comment: This is not a homework, but a part of the software that I am developing needs to calculate the Levenshtein distance between the strings belonging to two sets of strings. In order to build the 1st sets, I should take a list of strings and append a string to each of these strings: since this string is always the same, it is not convenient to iterate over the entire list to produce a new list. For these reason, I created my own implementation of a `CharSequence`... Just out of curiosity I was wondering whether there was already a class of this kind or a better alternative.

Comment: @enzom83: I understand up to the point you say it's not "convenient to iterate over the entire list".  Why isn't it convenient? Is this list "very large" - is this a performance issue?  (As an aside, I don't know a standard "composite char sequence" class -- I'm just interested in your problem).

Comment: What about iterating over a collection where get() is overridden to dynamically prefix the value returned? (I'm sure that violates a number of collection conventions)

Comment: @GregKopff: This list could be very large, then it is a performance issue (mainly in mobile computing).

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of a general data structure called a *rope*, which arranges segments of an array (of characters or otherwise) in a linked list or tree.  The goal is usually to speed up insertions or deletions in the middle of the array/string, or to support nondestructive operations with minimal copying, but you can use it to save memory by sharing the list/tree elements holding your shared substring of interest.  [This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ropes/index.html) begins with a brief overview of ropes, though it's more focused on efficient update operations than substring sharing.

The Java standard library doesn't include a rope implementation, but it's easy enough to either write your own or try an existing library like the one described in the article.  Library recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow, so I can't provide more direction than that.